# Memory warning/performance issues

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

iOS 6 SDK. Xcode 4.5.

Using storyboard and arc. I am making an application that consists of a number of calculators that compute various formulas. On one scene, I'm using 8 `UIButton`s that have a PNG file as a background image, and they are labelled as different formula categories to allow the user to navigate to 8 different formulas which are contained in 8 different scenes.

I'm using modal segues and am utilizing the `[self.presenting dismissViewController]` method to dismiss each scene. That all works fine.

On one calculator in particular, I've set up the scene to resemble an actual calculator. I used a `UIImageView` with a `UILabel` on top of it to act like a display. Even without code attached to it, when running on my device, I notice that the transition gets hung up when segueing to that scene. I'm not sure why. Also, whenever I hit a button I get a receives memory warning in the console. I'm also showing a leak in instruments.

This app works perfectly in the simulator but not on the actual phone. I'm not sure what's wrong. Could it be my compiler settings? Or is it the fact that I'm not programmatically setting up the button images? Even when there is just a `UIImage` with a blue picture PNG and a label on top of it, no buttons or a viewcontroller for this view, it still  gets hung up.

I'd appreciate any tips or tutorials or just plain tell me what I'm doing wrong lol.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I was using a very high resolution image on each of those buttons. When I replaced it with a low resolution image the memory issue went away